# WebSQL in ClojureScript?

Tags: web-sql, clojurescript

I'm having some trouble formatting a ClojureScript wrapper for websql.  The main problem is that JavaScript uses tx and err arguments for websql that work without being defined.  When the ClojureScript version runs, the code throws an error because tx was undefined.  Here is some sample code to follow along with a [websql tutorial from PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database) I was trying:

```
(defn populateDB [tx]
  (.executeSql tx ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id unique, text)"))
  (.log js/console "table added"))

(defn errorCB [err]
  (.log js/console (str "There was an error" (.code err))))

(defn successCB []
  (.alert js/window "It worked!"))

;; Run the transactions
(def db
  (.openDatabase js/window "Database" "1.0" "Cordova Demo" 1024))

(.transaction db (populateDB) (errorCB) (successCB))
```

Is there any way to get this to work or any libraries that already exist for websql + ClojureScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this question was kind of dumb.  I should have looked at it more before posting :p.  For reference, here's one way to write this:

```
(def db
  (.openDatabase js/window "Database" "1.0" "Cordova Demo" 1024))

(.transaction db.
              (fn [tx]
                (.executeSql tx "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)"))
              (fn [err]
                (.log js/console.
                  (str "There was an error " (.code err))))
              (fn []
                (.log js/console "It worked!")))
```